# $SO(3)$ diffeomorphiс to a spherization of tangent bundle of two-dimensional sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $\xi:Y\to X$ be a vector bundle.

Spherization of this bundle is the quotient space $(X\backslash \Theta) / \sim $ (here $\Theta$ is a graph of the zero section of the bundle) with equivalence relation $\sim$: $u\sim v$ if $\xi(u)=\xi(v)$ and $u=\lambda v$, where $\lambda>0$.

How to prove that $SO(3)$ diffeomorphiс to a spherization of tangent bundle of two-dimensional sphere?

Comment: Think about the action of $SO(3)$ on the orthonormal oriented frame bundle of the 2-sphere. Then relate the above bundle to the circle bundle you are interested in. What book are you reading?

Comment: @studiosus Our lecturer said just a few words about spherization and he told that it can be used to prove this theorem. I am just interested in it. I dont know any books where this topic may be.So, if you can name some good books, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: I prefer thinking about subsets as opposed to quotients:  to that end, your spherization is bundle isomorphic to the subset of $Y$ consisting of all vectors of unit length (in some chosen metric).  Of course, you have to choose a metric (and the spherization avoids this), but it just seems so much more concrete to me written as a subset of $Y$.  Perhaps this point of view helps?  (I don't have time to write up a full response now - sorry!)

Comment: I've voted to close, as you are asking questions - which you openly acknowledge you've received from a class - and not providing any of your own work.

Comment: @SteveD It wasn't a question or homework. That was just a remark by lecturer. And i am interested in a proof. In my view your claims are unfounded.

Comment: It is certainly a hot topic on this site, but I (among others) do not believe questions - without context or some work of your own - deserve to be kept open. It is an interesting question, and I am sure you will get the required references, but it seems asymmetrical when everyone else is doing the work for you, no?

Comment: @SteveD I don't want to rise a long argument, but what's your problem? As for me this question is better than a lot of other questions which fill the site (how to calculate the limit and so on). And what's the problem if someone will find this question interesting/give the answer to it? Anyway, act like you want. Cause closing question is much simplier than answering to it.

Comment: First of all: I don't have a problem.  I am not the one asking for help on a question and lazily doing none of the work myself.  Secondly, "better" is very subjective.  Many of those limit questions are posed a heck of a lot better than yours is. Thirdly, it's not about the question being "interesting"; it's about the asker having the respect for the other users here to show what they've done and why they care.

Answer (score 5):

Let $Q$ be the spherization of the tangent bundle of the standard unit 2-sphere $S^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Define a map $\phi: SO(3)\to Q$ as follows. An element $g\in SO(3)$ is a $3\times 3 $ matrix, whose columns are a positively oriented orthonormal basis $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ of $\mathbb R^3$ (with respect to the standard inner product and orientation on $\mathbb R^3$). In particular,  $v_1\in S^2$. The tangent space $T_{v_1}S^2=(v_1)^\perp$, hence $v_2\in T_{v_1}S^2$. Let $[v_2]=\mathbb R^+ v_2\in Q$ be the corresponding equivalence class. Finally define $\phi(g):=[v_2]$. To show that $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism we construct an inverse $\psi:Q\to SO(3)$ as follows. Given an element $[v]\in Q$, where $v\in T_{v_1}S^2$, $v\neq 0$, let $v_2=v/\|v\|$ and $v_3=v_1\times v_2$ (vector product). Then the matrix $g$ whose columns are $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is in $SO(3)$ so we can define $\psi([v])=g.$ It is quite easy to show that $\phi,\psi$ are inverse to each other hence $Q$ is diffeomorphic to $SO(3)$.